# CNAME problem: godaddy- Kindly help

Tags: cname-record, godaddy

I would like to point same location by 3 domains.

1. abc.com -> main domain : ip 123.123.123.123
2. 1st-pointing-abc.com
3. 2nd-pointing-abc.com

Now, domain with godaddy and hosting too.

How will I chnage CNAME and A record in case of 1st-pointing-abc.com and 2nd-pointing-abc.com?

Right now----
1st-pointing-abc.com:
A Record: @ ip:123.123.123.123
CNAME: www "points to" abc.com

What I am doing wrong? I am getting the message:
Quote:
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
godaddy says:
Quote:
1st-pointing-abc.com has no files to
pull up. Since it's custom dns, they are limited to how much support
the can provide.
any help greatly appreciate. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like this is a web server issue - you're probably using name-based virtual hosts, but only have a server name directive for the main domain.

Assuming you're using Apache, you probably just have a "ServerName 1.com" directive. You'll also need to add "ServerAlias 2.com" and "ServerAlias 3.com" directives.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing but it sounds to me like you need to set up host headers on your web site to match the CNAME records you've created.

Comment: how can I point 3 domains to one domain using DNS service?

Comment: say, 1.com is main domain and have hosting account. 2.com & 3.com need to pint to 1.com. So that if user visit 2.com then contenet will remain same as 1.com but browser url will be 2.com. Need to do it using is it possible?

Comment: I just tested this in W2K8 DNS and IIS 7 so I assume it will work with other DNS and web servers:

I created a CNAME called "www" in my "this.com" DNS zone with a FQDN of "www.that.com", added host headers of "www.this.com" to the web site at "www.that.com" and it worked exactly as you're requesting.

I must admit that in your original question you didn't state that you wanted the URL to stay unique for each domain name, that's why I posted my original answer.

Comment: You may have a problem as they would also need to configure the web server to accept 2.com and 3.com as an alias for 1.com. It is not just a DNS issue but also a web server issue.

Comment: @sybreon: I said that already, twice. Add host headers to the web server for the other two names.